# Topology of the moduli space of a 2-dim closed surface

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology

Consider the moduli space $\cal{M}_{\Sigma_g}$ of a 2-dim closed surface $\Sigma_g$ of genus $g$. What is the topology of such a moduli space $\cal{M}_{\Sigma_g}$?
For example, what is $\pi_n ( \cal{M}_{\Sigma_g} )$?

It appears that $\pi_1 ( \cal{M}_{\Sigma_1} ) = SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.
I like to know  $\pi_n ( \cal{M}_{\Sigma_1} )$ and more general $\pi_n ( \cal{M}_{\Sigma_g} )$.

In higher $d$-dimension do we have results for $\pi_n ( \cal{M}_{S^d} )$ and  $\pi_n ( \cal{M}_{(S^1)^d} )$?

== added:

Here "moduli space" mean space of smooth manifolds. The "moduli space" may have "fixed points" -- the fixed point of mapping class group. To obtain
$\pi_1 ( \cal{M}_{\Sigma_1} ) = SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$, those fixed points seems need to be removed.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the "moduli space" of a manifold?

Comment: When you say "space" do you mean a topological space or an orbifold? For instance, $M_{1,0}$ is simply connected as a topological space but not as an orbifold. Also, what do you mean when you ask "what is" about, say, the fundamental group? Are you asking for a presentation?

Comment: This is in reference to your edit.  The "space of smooth manifolds" and the "space of piecewise linear manifolds" are discrete.  You can't deform smooth or PL manifold structures.  What you can deform are various kinds of metrics or complex structures.  I think you should look closely at the Farb-Margalit book in the answer that Sam Nead left, which discusses such things on two-dimensional oriented surfaces.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you are asking about $\mathcal{M}_2$, the *moduli space* of hyperbolic metrics on (say) the genus two surface $\Sigma_2$ (up to isometry). This is a much studied object.  It is isomorphic to the moduli space of smooth complex curves (up to isomorphism) and also to the moduli space of Riemann surfaces of genus two (up to bi-holomorphism).

There are various ways to place a topology on $\mathcal{M}_2$. Interestingly, these all seem to give the same result.  The space is then (as I recall) contractible.  However, it is more natural to equip $\mathcal{M}_2$ with a certain natural *orbifold* structure.  This done, the orbifold fundamental group becomes the *mapping class group*, and the universal cover is *Teichmuller space*.  Since Teichmuller space is an open ball, all of the higher homotopy groups of $\mathcal{M}_2$ (considered as an orbifold) vanish.

You can find details of the above, and much more, in the book *Primer on mapping class groups*, by Farb and Margalit.

If we instead discuss $d$-dimensional manifolds (for $d > 2$) then matters are even more complicated - one needs to specify which structures one is collecting into a moduli space.